# How do I observe which order created by admin(magento backend) or customer(frontend)

Tags: orders, backend, create

How to observe who create new order in  Backend. Should I add new grid or new status.

Answer (score 1):

Create new field to order table 
when order created

trigger event on using event

```
adminhtml_sales_order_create_process_data event
```

it s params

```
 $observer->getEvent()->getOrderCreateModel();
  $observer->getEvent()->getRequestModel();
   $observer->getEvent()->getSession();
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27028747/2729501) getStoreId doesn't work after 1.6 because Magento started forcing to select a Store even for backend.

Alternative:

```
if(!empty($order->getRemoteIp()){
  //placed online
}
else{
  // placed by admin
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every order has a `store_id`, when entered through administration it will either be `0` (for 'admin' store) or `null`.

```
if ($order->getStoreId()) {
    // was placed via frontend
}
```

Don't use `getStore()` as that won't always return the admin store object reliably.

Comment: I don't think that's true. When creating an order from the backend you are required to select a store view for which you associate the order. When calling `$order->getStoreId()`  you will get that value. Also the OP asked how you can observe 'who' created an order in the backend. Not 'which' orders were created in the backend...unless this is a 'language barrier' problem